# Rocketeer deploy to AWS EC2 instance not execute the latest release

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autodeploy, rocketeer

I have an Laravel application, and I use [Rocketeer](http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu) to deploy the app. After deploy

[image: EC2 instance]

It showing that the symlink is actually pointed to the latest release, but then, when I refresh the page, it still refer to the older release.

I really have no idea what is going on. Because this issue doesn't happen in [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/abb622813f68) as well as other hosting.

Please help

Comment: whats your infra on amazon ? do you have any cache level ?

Comment: is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But not sure about the cache level _(this is my first time using AWS)_. Where to check the cache level?